# Identify an adjective

Tags: parts-of-speech

I've been stuck with this problem for three days.

> In the sentence 'My name is John', is 'name' used as an adjective or a
>   noun?

Comment: Three days? What prompted you to consider that *name* might be an adjective in your sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one thing that could be said to be an adjective in your sentence, and that is not *name*. As you said, *name* is a noun.

On the other hand, *my* is variously classified as a "possessive adjective", "possessive determiner" or "possessive pronoun". Depending on who you are talking to, they may or may not admit *my* to be an adjective.